# How to use Look up In Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a reference table called customer that has cust_id, cust_name ..., there are also other tables that have cust_name, cust_location....so on. I need to look up cust_location using cust_name from all these tables. how do I write the query in oracle SQL?

```
select cust_id, cust_name from customer
from (
    select cust_name as cust_location from tb1
    union all
    select cust_name as cust_location from tbl2
    union all
    select cust_name as cust_location from tbl3
    )
```

[image: list of tables]
expected result.......looks like

[image: expected result]

Comment: Seems like you need to familiarize with `JOIN` and the "keys" that relate the tables (which you have not provided in your question).

Comment: Besides the question, why you are doing like `cust_name as cust_location` ? Sample data and expected result would really help.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you mean by "look up".

Comment: for a specific cust_name, the cust_location supposed to present only in one of these tables(tb1, tb2,tb3...) if it present in tb1 the value of cust_location should be null for the other tables. so I need to look up and list out the cust_location by the table where it's present

Comment: How do you expect the result to be look alike ? Could you add your expected result as well.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 expected result added in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there..

```
select cust_location, table_name
from (
    select cust_name as cust_location, 'tb1' as table_name from tb1
    union all
    select cust_name as cust_location, 'tb2' as table_name from tbl2
    union all
    select cust_name as cust_location, 'tb3' as table_name from tbl3
    )
```

You can get Oracle's help to write this, actually:

```
SELECT 'select cust_name as cust_location, '''|| table_name ||''' as table_name from ' || table_name || char(13) || chr(10) || 'union all'
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name = 'CUST_NAME'
```

This SQL will generate an output that is the SQL in brackets in the first one; copy it out of the results grid and paste it into the query window

Answer (score 0):

You want all locations regardless of the customer. Some locations are null and must be ignored. I suppose that locations can occur more than once in a table, so I am using `DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct cust_name as cust_location, 'tb1' as table_name from tb1 where cust_name is not null
union all
select distinct cust_name as cust_location, 'tb2' as table_name from tbl2 where cust_name is not null
union all
select distinct cust_name as cust_location, 'tb3' as table_name from tbl3 where cust_name is not null
```